# Windows 10 webcam works on UWP but not on standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine, win-universal-app, webcam, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I have tried to show a usb webcam video in a simple app. I tried it through Unity3d, regular C# project and a UWP project. in unity3d the same code works when the target is windows 10 store and the app manifest declares webcam usage, and when I compile it to a standalone x86/x64 app the camera is turned on and the app crashes. I also wrote a simple UWP app using the windows 10 camera api and it worked fine but the .net 4.5/4.6 crashed like the unity app. I also tried accessing the camera through OpenCv but no luck. I think it's the webcam authorization in windows 10 but I do not know how to set it for standalone apps. Microsoft claims that only store apps are subject to the camera authorization setting but in real life the camera causes a crash. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a potential bug. Could you post the c# code you are running that is causing the crash and can you find the error message/code associated with the exception causing the crash?